# Typo3 override backend classes

Tags: class, typo3, overriding

It's been a few weeks I work on Typo3 6.2 and I want to know **how to override Typo3 Core classes**.

In my case, **I have to edit the way *select html objects* are displayed** (I want to add optgroup but Typo doesn't allow us to do it). So I edited the file "FormEngine.php" (typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Form) and now it works.
But this isn't healthy for future upgrade.

**Is there a way to override core classes like any other CMS would allow us to do ?**
And I haven't been able to find something on the Internet and I think it could be useful.

Comment: Where do you want to add which optgroup? There probably is a way to do it without changing the core.

Comment: In the back-end, on the "edit record" panel. One field references "attributes" sort by "attribute families" (displayed as optgroups).
But that example is not the real point : overriding those classes would be useful for future dev.

Comment: See biesiors answer - it is possible to do such stuff, but it is not done by overriding core classes. It is done via user functions, hooks, plugins, a signal/slot mechanism and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of modifying source code of CMS you can just declare a field with a `user` type and then point your custom `userFunc`

[From the ref](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/User/Index.html):

```
'tx_examples_special' => array (
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:examples/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:fe_users.tx_examples_special',
        'config' => array (
                'type' => 'user',
                'size' => '30',
                'userFunc' => 'Documentation\\Examples\\Userfuncs\\Tca->specialField',
                'parameters' => array(
                        'color' => 'blue'
                )
        )
),
```

**TIP:** Using this approach, you can create ANY type of field you need, it can be i.e. *Google Maps* selector, set of fields with common dependencies filled by JS, etc, etc.

Comment: Ok, so I have to create a new field type if I can't find the one I want.
It's enough for me to make it clean. Thank you :)